# Webhook and javascript for DialogFlow, where do I find documentation?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to learn DialogFlow (Google assistant) and I'm not so experienced in Javascript. I'm looking at various examples like [Build Actions for the Google Assistant](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html#5) Level 2, 3 e.t.c.

But it's like you're supposed to know already how the javscript side of things (the code deployed to Firebase, Node.js) works. I've found the [API reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/index.html) but it's very extensive. I just want to look up things from the Javascript code examples – say, like a description of the method `.intent`in the `dialogFlow` object and which other methods there are in this class. But I've no idea where to find things like this. When I search I end up in the wrong places.

Answer (score 1):

Part of what the issue may be is that you're mixing up two different, but related, technologies. Actions on Google are the tools for building for the Google Assistant. It *can* use Dialogflow as its Natural Language Processing system, and most people do, but it doesn't have to. Similarly, Dialogflow *supports* the Google Assistant as one of its platforms, but it also supports other platforms.

Adding to this confusion is that each has their own library that is targeted for their specific needs. The codelabs that you pointed to use the ["actions-on-google"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) library, while the documentation link you pointed to goes to the "dialogflow" library.

Documentation for Conversational Actions can be found at https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview. Under the [reference](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview) page there, you'll find a link to the [documentation for the library](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.12.0/index.html) (and rather than following this link, you should go to the developers page, since this links to a specific version of the library). You may find this documentation difficult to read, since it has classes that aren't relevant to you, but are there to abstract away differences between different version of the Actions on Google and Dialogflow protocols.

That documentation, however, can be a little difficult to read. It doesn't make clear, for example, that the typical lines to setup the application

```
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});
```

are creating an instance of a [DialogflowApp](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.12.0/interfaces/_service_dialogflow_dialogflow_.dialogflowapp.html). Or that the object that is passed to your handler and typically named "conv":

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  // Do things
});
```

is an instance of [DialogflowConversation](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.12.0/classes/_service_dialogflow_conv_.dialogflowconversation.html).

Comment: Thanks, those two links to DialogflowApp & DialogflowConversation seems to be what I was partly looking for. They are about DialogFlow but are located under actions-on-Google so I still find the relationships rather confusing but a bit clearer hopefully.

Comment: Dialogflow is an NLP with which you can build chatbots for different platforms. Actions on Google is used to build Google assistant actions and integrates very easily with Dialogflow because they are both owned by Google. The documentation about Dialogflow on the actions on google site talks alot about the integration between Dialogflow and Google Assistant, thats why you can find it there. The normal Dialogflow docs are more about building chatbots for any platform in general.

Comment: Dialogflow is a toolkit you can use to build an Action. That part of the actions-on-google library provides support for building an Action using the Dialogflow toolkit. Other parts of the library provide support for building a Smart Home Action or for building an Action without the Dialogflow toolkit (using what they confusingly call the Action SDK).

Comment: And you say "partly" looking for. What else were you looking for?

Comment: I'm also looking for more not-too-complex beginners info on how the javascript side and the dialogflow side speaks to each other. When I look at the Response tab in the Actions Console there's code which I don't know where it comes from and how it's constructed by the javascript side. Same thing with the request tab.

Comment: I'd suggest asking that as a new question. It is a good question, but has a fairly involved answer that is not quite related to the question/answer here.